# redirect to new server without login again in spring mvc

Tags: spring, apache, model-view-controller, shiro, mirroring

I have two version of one project on two server and I want to redirect some of user to use second server for testing new version and they don't understand. I use spring MVC and apache shiro . how can I redirect user after login without making user to login again ?

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: you should use some single sign on mechanism like CAS o tomcat realm

Comment: You could share sessions: 
https://stormpath.com/blog/hazelcast-support-apache-shiro